# RNSharedElementTransition is not available, did you forget to link `react-native-shared-element` into your project

Tags: react-native

I am using "react-navigation-shared-element": "5.0.0-alpha0","react-native-shared-element": "^0.7.0" and react-navigation 5

I am getting this warning **RNSharedElementTransition is not available, did you forget to link `react-native-shared-element` into your project?**
Nothing breaks though, it just doesn't work.
Manual linking is not there in the docs of react-native-shared-animation

My react version is 16.9

My Stack Navigator

const Stack = createSharedElementStackNavigator()

```
<Stack.Navigator headerMode='none'>
            <Stack.Screen name='Resource' component={Home}  />
            <Stack.Screen 
                name='Resource_Detail' 
                component={ResourceDetail}
                sharedElementsConfig={(route, otherRoute, showing) => {
                    const { id } = route.params;
                    return [{
                        id: id,
                        animation: 'move'
                    }];
                }}  />
        </Stack.Navigator>
```

SharedElement in Home

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Resource_Detail', { thumb, name, author, url, subCode, semesters, data, id })}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <SharedElement id={`${id}`}>
          <Image style={styles.thumbImg} source={{ uri: thumb }} />
        </SharedElement>
        <Text style={styles.secondaryText}>{author} </Text>
        <Text style={[styles.primaryText, { color }]}>{name}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

SharedElement in Resource Detail

```
<SharedElement id={`${id}`}>
    <Image style={styles.img} source={{ uri: thumb }} resizeMode='cover' />
</SharedElement>
```

Answer (score 0):

> react-navigation@5 is not supported

See [documentation](https://github.com/IjzerenHein/react-navigation-shared-element#installation) (last sentence in the installation section)